# Create new element with doctrine entity manager?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-7

I use doctrine entity manager in my script, select and update works always, so entity manager is initialized correctly:

```
$article = $entityManager->find('Models\Article', 5);
echo $article->getTitle();
or:
$article->setTitle('Updated!');
```

but when I try to create/save new element then the page breaks, the code is:

```
$item = new Article();
$item->setAuthorId(1);
$item->setTitle('Created item!');
$entityManager->persist($item);
$entityManager->flush();
```

It's created like on official [documentation page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities)

What I do wrong here?

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: What does "then the page breaks" mean?

Comment: @Youssef I tried now in a blank page, after I do "flush()" then I get redirect error, in firefox is this the message "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: can you check your logs?

Comment: There is nothing from today...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you can't specify the relation of the object with the `Author` entity:

```
$item->setAuthorId(1);
```

Probably your entity `Article` Have a relation with the entity `Author`. In this case you should have a proper setter method (simple `setAuthor(Author $author)` ) that assign the reference of an Author object. In this case you could use the following:

```
$item->setAuthor($entityManager->find('Models\Author', 1););
```

Or Better

```
$item->setAuthor($entityManager->getReference('Models\Author', 1););
```

You could also use a short way of reference the class object with the `class`  keyword, as example:

```
$item->setAuthor($entityManager->getReference(Author::class, 1););
```

Hope this help

Comment: There was also a other PHP error, but also relation, thanks people :)